# Include frequencies of NA a bubble plot

Tags: r, plot

I've got a data frame that looks like:

```
Data<- data.frame(item1=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, NA, 5, NA, NA), 
                  item2=c(1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                  item3=c(1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                  item4=c(1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 5, NA, 3, NA, NA),
                  item5=c(1, 5, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, NA, NA, 1, NA))
```

and I've got a function defined,  that extract column frequencies and plot it without NA's

```
frequencies <- function(x,K=5)
{
  p <- length(x) # items
  n <- nrow(x) # observations
  r <- (5, NA) # values
  myf <- function(y) # extract frequencies
  {
    y <- y[!is.na(y)]
    y <- as.factor(y)
    aux <- summary(y)
    res <- rep(0, r)
    res[1:r %in% names(aux)] <- aux
    100 * res / sum(res)
  }

  freqs <- apply(x, 2, FUN = myf) #  apply myf by columns
  df2 <- expand.grid(vals = 1:r, item = 1:p) # all possible combinations
  df2$freq <- as.numeric(freqs) # add frequencies

  # graph
  plot(df2$item,df2$vals,type="n",xlim=c(1,p),ylim=c(1,r),xaxt = "n",
       xlab="", ylab="", ann=FALSE)


  axis(1, labels=FALSE)
  labs <- paste(names(x))   ##labels=c("v1", "v2", ...)
  text(1:p,  srt = 60, adj=0.5, pos=1, las=2,
       labels = labs, xpd = TRUE, par("usr")[1], cex.main=0.8, offset=1)



  points(df2$item,df2$vals,pch=22,col="black", bg="gray", cex=(df2$freq/n)*K)
}
```

I would like NA's to be ploted as a "value" (in y coordinate) so my plot can look similar to that one (that has been edited with an editor, no R): 
[image]

Thank you in advance,

Angulo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility where you `melt` your data to long format, then count with `table` using `exclude = NULL` to also count `NA`. Check `scale_size_area` if you want to make frequencies proportional to area rather than width of the squares.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

Data2 <- melt(Data)
Data3 <- with(Data2, as.data.frame(table(variable, value, exclude = NULL)))
Data3 <- Data3[!is.na(Data3$variable), ]

ggplot(data = Data3, aes(x = variable, y = value, size = Freq)) +
  geom_point(shape = 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's a good solution for what I wanted. Do you know if that kind of plot has a specific name?

Comment: I think it's called [**bubble chart/plot**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_chart).

Comment: @AriadnaAngulo, I changed the title of your question from "frequency plot" to "bubble plot", which I believe is a more common way to refer to such plots.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
#u Useful packages:
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Loop over variables getting the counts of each value
counts <- lapply(Data, count)

# Combine the list of counts into a single data frame
all_counts <- do.call(rbind, counts)

# A bit of fixing.  Make x into a factor, and get the variable name
all_counts <- within(
  all_counts,
  {
    Value <- factor(x)
    Variable <- rep(names(counts), vapply(counts, nrow, integer(1)))
  }
)

# Remove NAs (it isn't very clear from the question whether you want NAs or not)
all_counts <- subset(all_counts, !is.na(x))

# Draw the plot.  sqrt is to scale area by freq rather than width by freq
(p <- ggplot(all_counts, aes(var, x, size = sqrt(freq))) + 
  geom_point(shape = 15) # shape 15 is a square. See ?points.
)
```

Comment: I cannot run this code due to an error when ploting:  Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous
Error in data.frame(x = function (x, y = NULL, na.rm = FALSE, use)  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 25

Comment: At a guess, you haven't converted the `x` or `y` axis variable to be a factor.